# Lesbegue Number Lemma Proof Detail

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Above is a proof of the Lesbegue Number Lemma, and I am having trouble understanding why such a $N$ exists that satisfies both $(i)$ and $(ii)$. I can see why each would be true individually:

$(i)$ - we can choose a sufficiently large integer to make this statement true

$(ii)$ - we can choose a sufficiently small radius, say $\frac{r}{4}$ , then as $y$ is a limit point of ${x_n}$ there exists some $x_N \ne y$ such that $x_N \in B_\frac{r}{4}(y)$  and so $(ii)$ is satisfied

But why would both $(i)$ and $(ii)$ be true at the same time? $(ii)$ only gives us some $N$, perhaps not sufficiently large to satisfy $(i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.

By subsequential convergence, there exists $\{N_k\}_{k=1}^\infty\subseteq\Bbb N$ an increasing sequence along which $x_{N_k}\overset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}y$. By definition of convergence, I know $\exists K\in\Bbb N$, for which $k>K$ implies $\mathrm{d}(x_{N_k},y)<\frac{1}{2}r$. So far, we agree.

The only point I will make: I am allowed to let $k$ be *any* (large) integer greater than $K$. As $N_k\to\infty$, I know there there is a $K'\in\Bbb N$, $k>K'$ implying $N_k>\frac{2}{r},\,\frac{1}{N_K}<\frac{1}{2}r$ (if $r>0$ is fixed beforehand).

So, I can just consider $K''=\max(K,K')$. If $k>K''$, then $\mathrm{d}(x_{N_k},y)<\frac{1}{2}r$ and $\frac{1}{N_k}<\frac{1}{2}r$ hold simultaneously. So let $N=N_k$ for any $k>K''$. You have a lot of 'choice'!

Answer (score 1):

$y$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. That means there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $y$. Thus for any fixed $r$, you will find an $N_0$ such that for all $k \geq N_0$ we have $x_{n_k} \in B_{\frac{r}{2}}(y)$. Hence you will certainly find an $x_N$ with sufficiently high index in $B_{\frac{r}{2}}(y)$.